# Get the coefficients of a polynomial with Numpy

Tags: numpy, polynomials, coefficients

I'm trying to get the coefficients of a `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial` obtained via
the `fit` method:

```
import numpy.polynomial as poly

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [16, 42.25, 81, 132.25, 196]

c = poly.Polynomial.fit(x, y, deg = 2)
print(c(5))
print(c)
```

This small program prints

```
196.00000000000006
poly([81. 90. 25.])
```

which is the correct value for `c(5)` but not for the polynomial coefficients, which are `2.25`, `7.5`, and `6.25`.
How do I get the actual coefficients?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit), the `.fit()` method returns

> A series that represents the least squares fit to the data and has the domain and window specified in the call. *If the coefficients for the unscaled and unshifted basis polynomials are of interest, do new_series.convert().coef.*

Running `c.convert().coef` on your data produces:

`array([2.25, 7.5 , 6.25])`